# different between using statemangement ex:Bloc and Router, navigator.pop().....?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, flutter-layout

what is the difference between using state management ex:Bloc and built in (Router) class with navigator.pop() and navigator.push().what is the exact use of blocs and when to use it?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

**State Management**

As the term defines it manages the State of the app. By state, it means when a user interacts with the app and the app changes its behavior then we can say it's a state change. The state can also be handled without any interaction from the user.
For Example

1. A user taps a button and you show him a message of "You tapped the button" (In case of user interaction).
2. A user is inside a chat app and the app receives the messages and updates the screen automatically with the new message (In case of no user interaction)

Note: Bloc is just a single way to handle state management, There are many other ways in the market.

**Router**

You have different screens for different purposes and you want to show/remove them upon different user interactions, here comes Router for your help.

For example,
You are inside a chat app, The first screen shows a list of conversations, and when you tap a conversation it takes you to the single conversation screen and you can also go back to the list of conversations. The changing of screens is done through router like `Navigator.of(context).push(//some screen)` and `Navigator.of(context).pop()` to go back.

Let comes to the real difference between State Management and Router because they look the same in my given example,
With State management, you can change a single object on a screen, for example, a piece of text. but with a router, you change the whole and there is no state management involved.

Comment: thanks for answering my question, but please let me summarize what i got from your answer and judge me, using (Router) navigate to and build a whole new screen but for changing a certain widget state within the same screen i should use state mangement like bloc or others.

Comment: Absolutely right